# Glyphicon Arrow help for sorting columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a table that displays a few different data attributes, I followed railscast #228 to make the columns sortable. Almost everything works except for one header named "groups" when I click that link my direction arrow break and it reverts back to the original header(I'll post a screenshot for clarity). I have a helper, a controller and a view that is rendering the function of the problem code, I will now show al the corresponding code and do my best to describe everything you'll need to know in order to help me. Here is my view.  You can see in the @people block that the `<td><%= person.groups.order(:id).pluck(:name).to_sentence %></td>` is the problem.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><%= sortable 'phone_number', 'Phone Number'%></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'subscribed', 'Subscribed'%></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'city' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'state' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'zip' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'country' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'groups' %></th>
    <th><%= sortable 'created_at', "Joined" %></th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

<% @people.each do |person| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= person.phone_number %></td>
        <td><%= person.subscribed? ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
        <td><%= person.city %></td>
        <td><%= person.state %></td>
        <td><%= person.zip %></td>
        <td><%= person.country %></td>
        <td><%= person.groups.order(:id).pluck(:name).to_sentence %></td>
        <td><%= time_ago_in_words person.created_at %> ago</td>
        </tr>
       <% end %>
```

Here is the sortable helper method

```
 def sortable(column, title = nil)
title ||= column.titleize
if column != sort_column
  css_class = nil
  direction = "asc"
elsif sort_direction == "asc"
  css_class = "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top"
  direction = "desc"
else
  css_class = "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"
  direction = "asc"
end
link_to "#{title} <span class='#{css_class}'></span>".html_safe, sort: column, direction: direction
end
```

here is my controller

```
  def index
@people = Person.order(sort_column => sort_direction)
@groups = Group.all
end
```

These are the sort methods in private

```
  def sort_column
  Person.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "phone_number"
  end

  def sort_direction
%w(asc desc).include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

here is a screenshot, this is the result of click the "Groups" Header. as you can see it reverts back to phone number. *note - Every other header sorts and displays the sorting arrow correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is not in the code you provided in your question, but in the code examples in the screencast. There is this method and I assume you implemented a similar method:

```
def sort_column
  Product.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
end
```

Note that `groups` in your table is not the name of a database column, but the name of an association to another model. Therefore this method would always return `"name"` (or I assume `"phone_number"` in your method).

You cannot order associations in active record in the same way than columns. There might be ways for a workaround, but that depends on your definition of what *sort by `groups` association* means: Do you want to sort that entries in the Groups column by group names, number of groups or group ids?

---

If you want to implement sorting by associations than you need to do two things. First allow the `sort_column` method to accept the associations name in addition to column names:

```
def sort_column
  sortables = Person.column_names + ['groups']
  sortables.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : 'phone_number'
end
```

And as a second step you have handle the special case of association ordering somewhere, perhaps in a `scope` in the model:

```
# in the model:
scope :sort_by, lambda { |options|
  if options.key == ['groups']
    scope = select('DISTINCT people.*').joins(:groups)
    if options.values == ['asc'] 
      scope.order('MIN(groups.name)') 
    else 
      scope.order('MAX(groups.name)')
    end
  else
    order(options)
  end
}

# in the controller
@people = Person.sort_by(sort_column => sort_direction)
```

Disclaimer: I am not sure if the scope actually works like you expect the sorting to work. Perhaps it would raise an error right away. it is just hard to write code like that without the possibility to actually run it against the database. But you get the idea: When you want to sort by association instead of column, it gets messy, because that has nothing to do with the screencast you looked at...

Comment: Yes, I want to sort by group names

Comment: @CameronBass How to sort by group names when there are multiple groups in that column? If there is a column with `visitor`, one with `visitor, staff` and one with `volunteer, dance` - what is your preferred order and why?

Comment: I was thinking just alphabetical like if there was a person in just `staff` and a person in `volunteer` the user could just sort that way. Admittedly It would not be very useful but it would keep continuity across the page.

Comment: In my opinion: Just remove the option to order by group name. You cannot order that column in a useful way. For example when you look for users that are in the staff group, you would still have to scan the whole table, because they might be at `dance, staff`, `staff`, `volunteer, staff`. From an UX point of view it doesn't make sense to provide a order option that just doesn't do anything helpful.

Comment: What does the method look like that you would use? Just for reference.

Comment: @CameronBass : I updated my answer to address your question. I hope you get the idea.